# Match regular expression named groups with dictionary key

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having some issues matching a string using regular expression with named capture groups against a dictionary list.

The string itself is a airport METAR (weather report):

> KLAX 050453Z 33003KT 10SM +TSRAGR HZ BR FEW010 SCT020 21/17 A3001 RMK
>   AO2 SLP161 T02060172

And here's the regular expression I'm using:

```
Regex MetarExpression = new Regex(@"\s(?<intensity>[\+\-VC]{1,2})?(?<descriptor>(MI|PR|BC|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ))(?<group>(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ|PY|PO|SQ|FC|SS|DS))+\s");
```

Basically I need to rewrite the weather groups (in this example, +TSRAGR, HZ and BR) to their respective translation, which would be "Thunderstorm, Heavy Rain, Hail, Haze, Mist"

Here is the code logic I currently have to do the translation:

```
Match m = MetarExpression.Match(metar);
if (m.Success)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if(phenom.ContainsKey(m.Groups["descriptor"].Value))
    {
        sb.Append(phenom[m.Groups["descriptor"].Value]);
        sb.Append(", ");
    }

    if (phenom.ContainsKey(m.Groups["intensity"].Value))
    {
        sb.Append(phenom[m.Groups["intensity"].Value]);
        sb.Append(" ");
    }

    foreach (Capture cap in m.Groups["group"].Captures)
    {
        if (phenom.ContainsKey(cap.Value))
        {
            sb.Append(phenom[cap.Value]);
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

Dictionary:

```
  static Dictionary<string, string> phenom = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
      {"-", "Light"},
      {"+", "Heavy"},
      {"VC","In the Vicinity"},
      // descriptor
      {"MI","Shallow"},
      {"PR","Partial"},
      {"BC","Patches"},
      {"DR","Low Drifting"},
      {"BL","Blowing"},
      {"SH","Showers"},
      {"TS","Thunderstorm"},
      {"FZ","Freezing"},
      // precipitation
      {"DZ","Drizzle"},
      {"RA","Rain"},
      {"SN","Snow"},
      {"SG","Snow Grains"},
      {"IC","Ice Crystals"},
      {"PL","Ice Pellets"},
      {"GR","Hail"},
      {"GS","Small Hail/Snow Pellets"},
      {"UP","Uknown Precipitation"},
      // obscuration
      {"BR","Mist"},
      {"FG","Fog"},
      {"FU","Smoke"},
      {"VA","Volcanic Ash"},
      {"DU","Widespread Dust"},
      {"SA","Sand"},
      {"HZ","Haze"},
      {"PY","Spray"},
      // other
      {"PO","Well-Developed Dust/Sand Whirls"},
      {"SQ","Squalls"},
      {"FC","Funnel Cloud Tornado Waterspout"},
      {"SS","Sandstorm"},
      {"DS","Duststorm"}
  };
```

The issue I'm having is that it's only capturing the first weather group (+TSRAGR) and not the other two.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: does your regex captures `RA`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want HZ and BR to be captured then try the below,

```
Regex MetarExpression = new Regex(@"\s(?<intensity>[\+\-VC]{1,2})?(?<descriptor>(MI|PR|BC|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ))(?<group>(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ|PY|PO|SQ|FC|SS|DS))\s(?<group1>(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ|PY|PO|SQ|FC|SS|DS))\s(?<group2>(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ|PY|PO|SQ|FC|SS|DS))");
```

Because a space character is in between, it blocks capturing. You need to specify another groups to capture `HZ` and `BR`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rE9nW6/1)

It would capture `+TSRAGR HZ BR` seperately.

```
\s(?<intensity>[\+\-VC]{1,2})?(?<descriptor>(MI|PR|BC|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ))(?<group>(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ|PY|PO|SQ|FC|SS|DS))(?<group1>(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ|PY|PO|SQ|FC|SS|DS))+\s(?<group2>(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ|PY|PO|SQ|FC|SS|DS))\s(?<group3>(DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|VA|DU|SA|HZ|PY|PO|SQ|FC|SS|DS))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rE9nW6/3)

Comment: Almost works! The only issue that I run into is that if there are less than three weather groups. Let's say that there is only +RA BR...it won't capture anything. Note, there is a max of three weather groups on a METAR report (there can also be none, too).

Comment: just make the captured group optional.

Comment: I made the capture group optional, but now the issue is that if there is only one weather group, it needs two (2) spaces after it for it to be captured. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zach An example would be better.

Comment: So for example, if I have this METAR: `KLAX 050553Z 34003KT 7SM -RA HZ FEW010 21/17 A3001 RMK AO2 SLP161 T02110172 10233 20206 51015` it should capture -RA and HZ...if I have `KLAX 050553Z 34003KT 7SM RA FEW010 21/17 A3001 RMK AO2 SLP161 T02110172 10233 20206 51015` it should capture RA.

Comment: it won't capture RA because we design the pattern to first match the + or - or V or C. But there is no one before RA in the above example.